# min and max values presentation column wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table @tbl having 3 column ind1,ind2 and ind3. I want to fetch max and min values from each column and 
present in following way.

```
declare @tbl table(ind1 float, ind2 float,ind3 float   )

insert into @tbl 
values (10,14,19 ),(11,22,13 ),(12,13,15 )
```

**My try:**

```
 SELECT MIN(IND1) IND1_MIN 
     ,MAX(IND1) IND1_MAX 
     ,MIN(IND2) IND2_MIN 
     ,MAX(IND2) IND2_MAX 
     ,MIN(IND3) IND3_MIN 
     ,MAX(IND3) IND3_MAX 
FROM @TBL
```

output required 1: 
    col_name min_value max_value 
    ind1     10         12 
    ind2     13         22
    ind3     13         19

output required 2:

```
  value  ind1 ind2  ind3 
  min     10   13    13
  max     12   22    19
```

I need both above output.

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Basically, you need to unpivot the data.  For a small amount of data, just use `union all`:

```
select 'ind1' as col_name, min(ind1), max(ind1) from @tbl union all
select 'ind2' as col_name, min(ind2), max(ind2) from @tbl union all
select 'ind3' as col_name, min(ind3), max(ind3) from @tbl ;
```

A more general solution is to use `apply` (or `unpivot`, if you really prefer):

```
select col_name, min(val), max(val)
from @tbl t cross apply
     (values ('ind1', ind1), ('ind2', ind2), ('ind3', ind3)
     ) v(col_name, val);
```

Note that both these solutions assume that all the columns involved have the same type.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful.Can you suggest me how can i generate following output as well with same data.

output required 2: 

      value  ind1 ind2  ind3 
      min     10   13     13
      max     12   22    19
Please see my edited question for correct format.Thanks in advance